# Play video when modal opens, pause when it closes

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have it so you click the image, the video opens up in a modal dialog, and then you have to click play. If you click off the video, it continues to play unless it has finished or has been paused beforehand.

If I set the video to autoplay, it will autoplay when the page loads, not when the dialog opens.

Code below:

```
<img class="img-responsive portfolioImages center-block"     src="images/church1.jpg" alt="" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#1">
<div id="1" class="modal fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog">
    <video controls class="center-block video">
        <source src="videos/big_buck_bunny.mp4" type="video/mp4">
        Your browser does not support HTML5 video.
    </video>
</div>
```

Comment: how do you open modal dialog?

Comment: and how is it closed? The solution is probably a simple javascript function where you tell the video to play when a user clicks the button and pause when the modal is closed

Comment: You click the image to open the dialog, then you click off the video to close it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you are using Bootstrap modal you can hook to its [`hidden.bs.modal`](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#modals) event to pause video:

```
$('.modal').on('hidden.bs.modal', function () {
    $('.video')[0].pause();
});
```

Here is a demo of this approach:

```js
$('.modal').on('hidden.bs.modal', function () {
    $('.video')[0].pause();
});
```

```html
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.4.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
<script src="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<img class="img-responsive portfolioImages center-block" src="http://lorempixel.com/100/100" alt="" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#1">
<div id="1" class="modal fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog">
  <video controls class="center-block video" style="width: 500px;">
    <source src="http://www.sample-videos.com/video/mp4/720/big_buck_bunny_720p_1mb.mp4" type="video/mp4"> Your browser does not support HTML5 video.
  </video>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

This one works perfectly, but you need to have `enablejsapi=1` in your src, like this for example:

```
<iframe src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/YOUR_VIDEO_CODE?rel=0&amp;controls=0&amp;showinfo=0&enablejsapi=1" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>


function playStopVideo() {
    var youtubeFunc ='';
    var outerDiv = $("#myModal");
    var youtubeIframe = outerDiv.find("iframe")[0].contentWindow;
    outerDiv.on('hidden.bs.modal', function (e) {
        youtubeFunc = 'stopVideo';
        youtubeIframe.postMessage('{"event":"command","func":"' + youtubeFunc + '","args":""}', '*');
    });
    outerDiv.on('shown.bs.modal', function (e) {
        youtubeFunc = 'playVideo';
        youtubeIframe.postMessage('{"event":"command","func":"' + youtubeFunc + '","args":""}', '*');
    });
}

playStopVideo();
```